# Deploy only a javadoc

Tags: maven, javadoc, java-9

My project uses asciidoclet to generate javadocs. Turns out that with Java 9 the Javadoc API has changed so much that the asciidoclet used by Maven's javadoc-plugin was never ported to Java 9+. So the only way to generate the Javadoc is by running it under Java 8.

I can exclude creating the Javadoc when deploying to maven central. But how can I just release the Javadoc to sonatype?

Comment: The asciidoclet is supported by javadoc tool(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#doclets)  which is part of the JDK. The maven-javadoc-plugin can not port that and will never do that. You have to change the used asciidoclet to get it working with JDK9+ ... Furthermore I would suggest to build with more recent versions of java JDK11+. Technically you can deploy artifacts to the staging repository as long as you don't closed the staging repository.

Comment: I'm deploying Java 8, 9, 10 versions to central, and working now on the 11 version. I only cannot deploy javadoc in 9+, because the asciidoclet does not work with Javadoc in Java 9+ anymore. Someone seems to have made a patch for Java 11 though. So I may just skip 9 and 10. Docs are identical anyhow.

Comment: I think skipping 9 and 10 makes a lot of sense, even without this specific problem. There is little point in supporting your lib for a Java version that gets no further security updates. Sticking to 8, 11 and maybe the latest (currently 14) suffices.

Comment: I'm using Java 11 and following the steps here: https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoclet, but i'm still lost on how to *actually* generate the html from the java classes. I have added plugins and dependencies to the pom.xml, but what is the command/steps to generate the html files? And where do they go after they're generated?

Answer (score 0):

It is simple

```
mvn javadoc:jar deploy:deploy
```

My mistake was that I used javadoc:javadoc. Stupid me.

So compile and deploy under Java 9+ with -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true and then run under java 8 again with javadoc and deploy. Works for now.